# Echo in an array iteration overwrites previous echo (PHP)

Tags: php, html, arrays

Currently I am doing this:

```
$lines = file('data/index');
    foreach ($lines as $value)
    list($title, $location) = explode("|", $value);
    echo '<div id="entry"><a href="'.$location.'">'.$title.'</a></div>';
```

And the contents of `data/index` is:

```
This is a test post|http://google.com 
Another test post|http://google.com
```

However, it only prints out the last line of that file. Almost like each "echo" is being overwritten by a new one. I'm obviously not doing this correctly. Why isn't it working and how can I make it perform the way I intend it to?

Comment: let me guess, you are coming from a python background?

Comment: @code_burgar In that case his indentation would have been right ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, only the third line is part of the loop. If you want to have both statements in the loop, you have to create a block:

```
foreach ($lines as $value) {
    list($title, $location) = explode("|", $value);
    echo '<div id="entry"><a href="'.$location.'">'.$title.'</a></div>';
}
```

Furthermore, `echo`ing HTML with PHP should be avoided. You should embed PHP into your HTML instead. It makes your code, especially your HTML markup easier to maintain and is less error prone.

**Reference**: [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I missed that. I'm new to PHP

Comment: @MaxMackie: This problem is not specific to PHP. It's the same in most other "C-based" languages.

Comment: I would disagree on echoing HTML being bad style per se.

Comment: @FeliX Kling: In response to the style comment, how should I properly iterate over a file's contents and turn it into HTML?

Comment: @MaxMackie Perhaps you're used to Python? In that language, the indentation of the code defines the block.

Comment: @MaxMackie if the rest of your file is "pure" PHP, I'd stick to this version for the sake of readability.

Comment: @FelixKling "You should embed PHP into your HTML instead." Disagree. Either you do proper templateing or you do it like he does. Embedding PHP in HTML is generally considered not-so-good practice.

Comment: @NikiC: There are always edge cases. But if a whole HTML page is created with PHP, then it is more appropriate to put all the logic at the top of the page, and only echo the data where it belongs, IMO. And there is nothing wrong with using PHP for templates, if done right.

Comment: @MaxMackie: It's fine for simple code. But if it gets more complex, separate your application logic from the presentation.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, I probably misunderstood what you meant. You were talking about PHP for templateing, I was more thinking about strange spagetti-code with intermixed chunks of HTML and PHP ;)

Answer (score 4):

You need curly braces {}. Without them, only the next line gets iterated over after a loop. So, only your list() is getting iterated over.

```
foreach ($lines as $value)
{ // <-- Important
    list($title, $location) = explode("|", $value);
    echo '<div id="entry"><a href="'.$location.'">'.$title.'</a></div>';
} // <-- Important
```

Comment: the next *statement*. that can be on the same line if you type a semicolon after the ) by mistake!

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
foreach ($lines as $value)
list($title, $location) = explode("|", $value);
echo '<div id="entry"><a href="'.$location.'">'.$title.'</a></div>';
```

Only the list part is in the foreach loop. You need:

```
foreach ($lines as $value)
{
    list($title, $location) = explode("|", $value);
    echo '<div id="entry"><a href="'.$location.'">'.$title.'</a></div>';
}
```

Comment: ack! didn't see the other answers until just now. _edit: +1 for Felix King's answer_